# Send messages from Azure Service Bus queue to new asb queue

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a message host that executes messages from asb queue. I want to create a new message host (scale up)(.NET core) when it first message host's load is up. In order to do so, I want to send some messages from one queue to another queue and then that (new) ,message host reads it from new asb queue. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways by which you can accomplish this:

- **Auto-forwarding**: You can configure auto-forwarding on the 1st queue to forward messages to the 2nd queue automatically. In this case, as soon as the message arrives in the 1st queue, it will be forwarded to the 2nd queue.  It will remove the message from the 1st queue though and both queues must be the part of same Namespace. You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding.
- **Azure Service Bus Triggered Function with Azure Service Bus Output Binding**: In this case, the Function will be triggered when a message arrives in the queue. Because of output binding, this Function will send the message to another queue. You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp.

Comment: thanks! The thing is let us say I have messages (say 10) in an order (say for processing code = A) and all this should be processed in sequence by a message host. Now suppose loads increases and some of the messages (of processing code = A)  are transferred to next queue and next message host to process. I want that the order of these messages processing remains intact.

Comment: Can you please ask a separate question for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73854244/send-messages-from-azure-service-bus-to-another-service-bus-when-application-has