# Unable to renew lock on session-enabled Azuer Servicebus Queue

Tags: python, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have checked every post on this site as well as the errors reported on the azure python SDK github page but I cannot figure this out. I am getting:

```
SessionLockLostError: The lock on the session has expired. Callers should request the session again.
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "azure_pipeline.py", line 119, in __call__
  await receiver.complete_message(msg)
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/envs/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/aio/_servicebus_receiver_async.py", line 806, in complete_message
  await self._settle_message_with_retry(message, MESSAGE_COMPLETE)
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/envs/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/aio/_servicebus_receiver_async.py", line 440, in _settle_message_with_retry
    self._check_live()
File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/envs/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/servicebus/aio/_base_handler_async.py", line 237, in _check_live
  raise SessionLockLostError(error=self._session.auto_renew_error)
azure.servicebus.exceptions.SessionLockLostError: The lock on the session has expired. Callers should request the session again.
```

My code is below. I have checked all the async samples and tried everything with the AutoLockRenewer() including passing it to the get_queue_receiver etc. I have also tried both

```
received_msgs = await receiver.get_messages()
and
async for msg in receiver
```

I have also tried putting the auto_lock_renewer.register() code before and after the message loop and other places. I have also tried renewing the message instead of the session but that does not work for session-enabled queues.

Right now, the

> msg_body = await self.run(msg)

is just calling time.sleep(120) and retuning a string.

```
    async def __call__(self):
    receiver = self.servicebus_client.get_queue_receiver(
        queue_name=self.request_queue,
        session_id=NEXT_AVAILABLE_SESSION,
        receive_mode=ServiceBusReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK,
    )
    async with receiver:
        try:
            async with AutoLockRenewer(
                max_lock_renewal_duration=300,
                on_lock_renew_failure=self.my_callback,
            ) as auto_lock_renewer:
                auto_lock_renewer.register(receiver, receiver.session)
            # received_msgs = await receiver.receive_messages()
            async for msg in receiver:
                logger.info(
                    f"Session locked until: {receiver.session.locked_until_utc}"
                )
                logger.info(f"Received msg {msg}")
                msg_body = await self.run(msg)
                sender = self.servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(
                    queue_name=self.reply_queue, session_id=msg.session_id
                )
                async with sender:
                    message_to_send = ServiceBusMessage(
                        msg_body, session_id=msg.session_id
                    )
                    await sender.send_messages(message_to_send)

                    logger.info("Message successfully sent!")

                # complete the message so that the message is removed from the queue
                await receiver.complete_message(msg)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info("CLOSING RECEIVER")
            await receiver.close()
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.error(f"Failed to process message with exception {e} \n {tb}")
```

Comment: try to use the AutoLockRenewer class to renew the lock on the session. You can register the AutoLockRenewer with the get_queue_receiver method to renew the lock on the session from the [refrence](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues.md)

Comment: Send messages from Azure Service Bus queue to [new asb queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853045/send-messages-from-azure-service-bus-queue-to-new-asb-queue)

Answer (score 0):

Unable to renew lock on session-enabled Azuer Servicebus Queue

The error message you are seeing is `SessionLockLostError: The lock on the session has expired. Callers should request the session again.` This error occurs when the lock on the session has expired.

I tried using the `AutoLockRenewer` class to renew the lock on the session. By this I can register the `AutoLockRenewer` with the `get_queue_receiver` method to renew the lock on the session.

- Using the source code from the [MSDOC](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues.md).

```py
async  def  process_message(message):
print("Received message:",  str(message))
async  def  receive_messages():
async  with  ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)  as  sb_client:
async  with  sb_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name,  session_id=session_id,  prefetch_count=10)  as  receiver:
renewer = AutoLockRenewer()
receiver._lock_renewer = renewer
async  for  message  in  receiver:
await  process_message(message)
await receiver.complete_message(message)
if  __name__ == "__main__":
import  asyncio
asyncio.run(receive_messages())
```

[image]

```py
def process_message(message):
    print("Received message:", str(message))
 
def receive_messages():
    with ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connection_string) as sb_client:
        with sb_client.get_queue_receiver(queue_name, prefetch_count=10) as receiver:
            renewer = AutoLockRenewer()
        receiver._lock_renewer = renewer
          for message in receiver:
              process_message(message)
       receiver.complete_message(message)
       if __name__ == "__main__":
    receive_messages()
```

- Refer this SO for Send messages from Azure Service Bus queue to [new asb queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853045/send-messages-from-azure-service-bus-queue-to-new-asb-queue).